# proxy a fuseki sparql endpoint with nginx and query with yasgui

Tags: nginx, fuseki

i've a running fuseki triplestore.
it's published trough a nginx proxy:

```
location /sparql {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030/my_dataset/query;
    }
```

i installed [yasgui](http://yasqe.yasgui.org/) and configured to use http://my_nginx/sparql

the error obtained is **400 no query parameter**:

```
POST http://my_nginx/sparql 400 (SPARQL Query: No 'query=' parameter)send @ jquery.js:9659jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9210YASQE.executeQuery @ sparql.js:86tab.yasqe.query @ tab.js:253(anonymous function) @ main.js:559jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4665elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4333
```

what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

found this example that solve (is very unclear that are needed two components, yasgui and yasr):

https://gist.github.com/LaurensRietveld/7d8beca5dbeb6b909b6f